# 翻訳の誤り: 「ロールバック」が誤記で「ロールバク」に

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, ヘルプ

> ヘルプ センター > 弊社のモデル
>   自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか?編集はどのように機能しますか?
>   https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing

の最終段落で誤記があります。

> #### ロールバックとは?
>
> ロールバクとは、質問または回答を編集履歴の以前のバージョンに戻すことです。この場合、ロールバック操作自体も編集履歴内の最新の項目として表示されます。

明らかに「ロールバック」です。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こういう単純なことは、報告しても直して貰えないのでしょうか。それとも他に報告の手段があるんでしょうか。

Comment: 気づいてないだけかも。[ヘルプ・センターの改善](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7/%E3%83%98%E3%83%AB%E3%83%97-%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E6%94%B9%E5%96%84)みたいに、[ヘルプ]タグを付けるとモデレーターさんが修正してくれそうな気がします。

Comment: @aterai さん、ありがとうございます。ヘルプタグを付けてみました。

Comment: モデレーターパワーを行使できるのは、ヘルプセンターの中でもいくつかの記事だけなのです。コミュニティーマネージャーのjmacさんをつっついてみますね。

Comment: @ento さんありがとうございます。直接 jmac さんに連絡取った方が良かったんですかね…その辺りの間合いが分からなくて（ @ を付けて良いのか分からないので今も付けてません。

Comment: @riocampos すみません！翻訳のワークフローを今改善中ですので、年明けからしばらく翻訳バグを管理できていないです。治すつもりですが、しばらくお待ち下さい。

Comment: @jmac さん、了解です。この記事と同時期に投稿した残り2件（[翻訳の誤り: 誤記および余分な促音](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1628/), [日本語に違和感: 日本版サイトなのに「できる限り正しい英語の綴りと文法を」](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1626/)）についてもご対応お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

更新しました：https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing

> ロールバックとは?
>
> ロールバックとは、質問または回答を編集履歴の以前のバージョンに戻すことです。この場合、ロールバック操作自体も編集履歴内の最新の項目として表示されます。